# Miktex runtime error!

Tags: errors, miktex, windows

When I compile `latex` for `pdflatex` for some times, the following error appears:

> Runtime Error! R6016 - not enough space for thread data.

I use tex editor `texmaker`. After this error, the `pdflatex` works very, very slowly (approximetly 1 minute). Is there ways, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4):

Please have a look on the Microsoft page http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126709/en-us.

Your windows system has a problem. Reboot your computer system. If the reboot does not help check which other programm you have running causing your problems as the microsoft site said.